# not able to select GCC (x86 32bit) tool chain in Qt

Tags: macos, qt

Iam not able to select gcc 32bit as the tool chain to compile my qt application. 
the following are the details.

```
QtCreator - 2.4.1 (64bit)
QtSDK     - 4.8.0 (64bit)
Platform  - OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2
Xcode     - 4.6.2
```

i wanted to compile my application with 32bit tool chain only. I can able to compile in
windows but in mac it is not. So please help me on this.

List of available tool chains as shown in `Qt creator->Preferences->Build&Run` are

```
GCC (x86 32bit)
GCC (x86 64bit)
GCC (ppc 32bit)
GCC (ppc 64bit)
```

But when i am trying to set tool chain under build settings of the project, it is listing only 
as follows

```
GCC (x86 64bit)
GCC (ppc 64bit)
```

what i have to do to get 32 bit as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Kit for this in Creator's settings. It's in Tools->Options->Build & Run. Then add that Kit in the settings of your project.

Unless of course the Qt libraries you've installed are 64-bit only. In that case, you obviously can't build 32-bit applications with them. If that's the case, you need to build Qt on your own for 32-bit.

Comment: Hi Nikos, i tried option u sugested. but it did not reflecting the change in my project. i can able to compile for 32 bit in the above case in Leopard (10.5.X), but not able to do in its successors SnowLeopard(10.6.X), Lion(10.7.X) & Mountain Lion(10.8.X). Please help.